# Single page app with ASP.NET MVC / Backbone- AJAX HOME PAGE

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to make my application fully ajaxified in terms of navigation between pages (using Backbone.js Routing).

So I basically did everything I want and all the pages load correctly without page refreshes EXCEPT THE HOMEPAGE. I isolated WHY this is happening but I dont know how to FIX it. It probably a very simple question for anyone that has worked with a single page app before.

So basically I have these backbone routes:

```
    routes: {
        "": "renderHome",
        "!/:page": "renderPage"
    },
    renderHome: function () {
        pageView.render("Home");
    },
    renderPage: function (page) {
        pageView.render(page);
    }
```

The Backbone PageView has render method like this:

```
 render: function (page) {
        $(this.el).load("Navigation/" + page);
 }
```

Basically, /Navigation/anypage loads via ajax (no refresh)
but /Navigation/Home causes a page refresh.

However, if I simple change the href on the homepage anchor 
FROM:

```
<a class="navigationTab" href=""><span>Home</span></a>
```

TO:

```
<a class="navigationTab" href="#!/Home"><span>Home</span></a>
```

it works the way it should. However I dont want my home page to be www.website.com/#!/Home  That is ugly!!

How can I keep the original format for the homepage (without the hashtag) and still have it load without a page refresh.

I suspect its because changing the window.location.hash to a blank value makes it reload the page but if theres a hashtag its like going to a different part of the page so theres no need for a reload. How can I prevent this??

```
$('.navigationTab').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what hashtags do is to set the url to the same url, but adding #(page) in it ... you may try it by adding a hash on any page you are visiting manually at the end and the page won't refresh.

You have two options

#### Option One - using pushState

It is a long story, and you will probably need to modify your whole website and server structure, since you'll probably remove all the hashtags when using pushState.

#### Option Two - set the home with a hashtag

```
<a class="navigationTab" href="/#"><span>Home</span></a>
```

by doing this you will set the router to Home but there will be a hashtag in the end

Comment: That really lame that those are the only 2 options because ive read pushState is only supported on the newest versions of the modern browsers, which is a concern. What will happen if I use pushState and somebody goes on from an unsupported browser. Will the page still load (with a refresh) or it wont load at all?

Comment: Well I can understand your anger, but let's take a look at the most popular Ajax applications ... for e.g. gmail, if you examine the URL's you'll se #inbox, #sent and whenever you load gmail.com it goes to #inbox... Something more... Let's take a look at klout.com (Backbone based) ... there is www.klout.com/#/[user] kind of url management. So this is probably the best for you ... to add /#/ after your main url address for home, or use pushState ( which isn't available in every browser )